# java Composite design pattern(Directory &File)

Tags: java

The outputs below are different. I don't know what's wrong and I have tried to correct many times. 
There has File and Folder two java files.And for the format, for a listed folder,there must be a "/" at the end and for each folder/file, the path must be the absolute path.

The output must be

```
dir1/
dir1/f1/
dir1/dir2/
dir1/dir2/f3/
dir1/dir2/f4/
dir1/dir2/dir3/
dir1/dir2/dir3/f5/
dir1/f2/
```

However,my output is

```
dir1/
dir1/f1/
dir1/dir2/
dir2/f3/
dir2/f4/
dir2/dir3/
dir3/f5/
dir1/f2/
```

Here is my code.

```
public class File implements Composite {
    public String name;
    //private ArrayList<File>a=new ArrayList<File>();


    public File(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }


    public void list() {

        System.out.print(name+"/");
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

#### Folder.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Folder implements Composite{
    public String name;
    public ArrayList b = new ArrayList();

    public Folder(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public void add(Object o) 
    {

        b.add(o);
    }

    public void list(){
           int e=b.indexOf(name)+1;
           System.out.println(name+"/");
           Composite r=(Composite) b.get(e); 
           for(int i=0;i<b.size();i++) {

               System.out.print(name+"/");



               Composite a=(Composite)b.get(i);

               a.list();
           }

    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you expect when you tried to print only folder name + file name for each file? How did you expect the parent folder of the folder containing the file being printed once per file in the subdirectory?

Comment: There are two lines of meaningless code:'int e=b.indexOf(name)+1;'  and 'Composite r=(Composite) b.get(e); '. Try to get the folder itself from the list which only contains the children folder/file, probably would throw an exception

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you need to track the parent folder of each `Folder`.

So the constructor needs to be `Folder(Folder parent, String name)`. The root (topmost) folder has `null` as parent.

When you print the name, you need to ask the current folder for it's path. The code for this method would be:

```
 public String getPath() {
     if(null == parent) return name;

     return parent.getPath() + "/" + name;
 }
```